# Trying to use shortcode for a plugin on custom homepage of Responsive theme

Tags: plugins, child-theme, homepage, responsive

The Responsive theme has a custom home page option, with a feature content div that is defaulted to an image. I cannot get shortcode for my slideshow plugin to work in this. I can insert html just fine, but no shortcode. Also, major noob here.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you doing to try to get your shortcode to work?

Comment: @s_ha_dum - I'm trying to put a slideshow where the featured content would be on the custom homepage. For some reason the shortcode for the slideshow plugin doesn't work in it. Here's a [post](http://themeid.com/docs/theme-options-featured-content/) about what I'm working with.

Comment: @JasonMcNamara So you are posting the slideshow shortcode inside that Featured Content box? We don't know how the plugin was written, but it's likely that the featured content box does not accept shortcodes.

Comment: "I'm trying to put a slideshow where the featured content would be"-- I got that @Jason but didn't know how your theme works. That link suggests the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is going to require a theme edit.

I am assuming that your shortcode is visible on the front-- something like `[gallery]`-- but not processed as a shortcode. If that is the case, you will need to find where that content is output in the theme and pass it through [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) before echoing it. That could be more or less difficult depending upon how the theme is written.

If the shortcode does not make it through to the front page at all, then I have to assume that shortcodes are stripped from that content when it is saved. That is a tougher fix and would require more information.

It is possible that the theme has a hook you can use to avoid a direct theme edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a shortcode from within a child-theme instead of within the content of a page, you can invoke it with a special function:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>
```

The code should be pasted in the active child-theme's functions.php